# Qt: Defining a custom event type

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have created a custom event in my Qt application by subclassing QEvent.

```
class MyEvent : public QEvent
{
  public:
    MyEvent() : QEvent((QEvent::Type)2000)) {}
    ~MyEvent(){}
}
```

In order to check for this event, I use the following code in an event() method:

```
if (event->type() == (QEvent::Type)2000)
{
  ...
}
```

I would like to be able to define the custom event's Type somewhere in my application so that I don't need to cast the actual integer in my event methods.  So in my event() methods I'd like to be able to do something like

```
if (event->type() == MyEventType)
{
  ...
}
```

Any thoughts how and where in the code I might do this?

Comment: Instead of the magic constant `2000`, you can use `QEvent::User`.

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel: +1. Also. Instead of "can use", I'd say **should use**. ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the event-type identifies your specific class, i'd put it there:

```
class MyEvent : public QEvent {
public:
    static const QEvent::Type myType = static_cast<QEvent::Type>(2000);
    // ...
};

// usage:
if(evt->type() == MyEvent::myType) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks!  Though I don't entirely understand why you made you revision that you did.

Comment: If initialized in the class definition, it can be used in integral constant expressions like with `case` in `switch` statements or as array bounds.

Answer (score 17):

For convenience, you can use the QEvent::registerEventType() static function to register and reserve a custom event type for your application. Doing so will allow you to avoid accidentally re-using a custom event type already in use elsewhere in your application.

Example:

```
class QCustomEvent : public QEvent
{
public:
    QCustomEvent() : QEvent(QCustomEvent::type())
    {}

    virtual ~QCustomEvent()
    {}

    static QEvent::Type type()
    {
        if (customEventType == QEvent::None)
        {
            int generatedType = QEvent::registerEventType()
            customEventType = static_cast<QEvent::Type>(generatedType);
        }
        return customEventType;
    }

private:
    static QEvent::Type customEventType;
};

QEvent::Type QCustomEvent::customEventType = QEvent::None;
```

Comment: This is a nice proposition, but you can skip the QEvent::None part:
    const QEvent::Type CustomEvent::EventType = static_cast<QEvent::Type>(QEvent::registerEventType());

Comment: And naming your example QCustomEvent is not very clever: it's the name of a Qt 3 class.

Comment: Also, you don't need a member variable. Just use a static local.

Comment: **WARNING** This is bad advice. This code will work only if you have one custom event type. You can't derive from this `QCustomEvent` class!

Answer (score 7):

The idiomatic way of dealing with such problems is to create a template wrapper class, leveraging [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). For each custom event type, such template represents a new type, thus a separate `staticType()` member exists for each type, returning its unique registered type.

Below I give three ways of identifying types:

1. By `staticType()` -- this is only useful *within* an invocation of the application, and is the type to be used with `QEvent`. The values *are not guaranteed to stay the same* between invocations of an application. They *do not* belong in durable storage, like in a log.
2. By `localDurableType()` -- those will persist between invocations and between recompilations with the same compiler. It saves manual definition of `durableType()` method when defining complex events.
3. By `durableType()` -- those are truly cross platform and will be the same unless you change the event class names within your code. You have to manually define `durableType()` if you're not using the `NEW_QEVENT` macro.

Both `localDurableType()` and `durableType()` differ betwen Qt 4 and 5 due to changes to `qHash`.

You use the header in either of two ways:

```
#include "EventWrapper.h"

class MyComplexEvent : public EventWrapper<MyComplexEvent> {
   // An event with custom data members
   static int durableType() { return qHash("MyEvent"); }
   ...
};

NEW_QEVENT(MySimpleEvent) // A simple event carrying no data but its type.
```

**EventWrapper.h**

```
#ifndef EVENTWRAPPER_H
#define EVENTWRAPPER_H

#include <QEvent>
#include <QHash>

template <typename T> class EventWrapper : public QEvent {
public:
   EventWrapper() : QEvent(staticType())) {}
   static QEvent::Type staticType() {
      static int type = QEvent::registerEventType();
      return static_cast<QEvent::Type>(type);
   }
   static int localDurableType() {
      static int type = qHash(typeid(T).name());
      return type;
   }
};

#define NEW_QEVENT(Name) \
   class Name : public EventWrapper< Name > \
   { static int durableType() { \
       static int durable = qHash(#Name); return durable; \
     } };

#endif // EVENTWRAPPER_H
```

Comment: I like the usage of the CRTP here but I wonder how you'll be sure that the variants using `qHash` do not collide with existing event types?

Comment: You can't be sure in general, but you can be sure for any specific program. You can statically check for collisions and get a "yes, there are collisions" or "no, there are no collisions" answer. So, sometimes the fact that there's no way to know in general doesn't preclude knowing it in specific circumstances.

Comment: But isn't this a very important point that should be mentioned in your answer? At last you don't include any provisions against collisions in your code.

Comment: The code itself doesn't have much to do. You'd use a static checker to verify presence of collisions, or lack thereof.