# How do events work in Qt?

Tags: qt, events

I have some questions about the general usage of Qt events. I'm new to Qt, and I am going to try out making a custom event. The questions I ask are related to this article: [Qt 4.8: The Event System](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.8-snapshot/eventsandfilters.html)

- **When does an event “occur”?** 
  In Qt's built in events, mouse clicks and key presses are put into a queue and then the functions are executed at the next frame. I’m especially wondering about this for custom events, because I’m not sure if it always occurs when a mouse is clicked. For custom events, is it when you send the event into the queue and then waits to be processed by the event() function at the next frame?
- **To create a custom event, must you make a class that inherits from QEvent and register an event with registerEventType() function?** 
  Is this the standard process, or can an event simply be a class? How does this function, registerEventType(), work?
- **Do custom events have a QEvent::Type?** 
   Is this the number between 1000 and 6563 that is given when using the registerEventType() function?
- **What is the recipient of an event?** 
   It seems to be in functions' parameters like postEvent(), sendEvent(), etc. However, I am not sure what this object is for.
- **Where is the actual code that is executed when an event is fired?** 
  Is it a function, or is it in the event() function of QObjects.

Also any working examples of Qt events (both built-in or custom) in action would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at Qt [Examples](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/all-examples.html) online or in QtSDK, there are tons of them.
IMO you didn't search hard.

Ad.1. It occurs after you fire it with QApplication::postEvent() or QApplication::sendEvent(). Not  immediately of course, because it has to go through the main loop, etc. The order of events should be preserved, though.

Ad.2. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248009/qt-defining-a-custom-event-type), second anwser.

Ad.3. Go to Ad.2.

Ad.4. This object will receive this custom event in QObject::customEvent() handler.

Ad.5. Go to Ad.4.

Comment: When you say the "main loop", is that the loop that is run every second to call functions that were put into the queue via an event?

Comment: Qt programs like any other GUI programs has a main loop. You can't see it, but it exists in QApplication::exec() function. It catches all kind of events (internal and external) and calls appropriate handlers in order of occurrence. I'm not sure what's your problem, to be honest ;) Just fire your events and catch them. No big deal.

Comment: Thanks, almost everything makes sense now. Unfortunately, there weren't any examples in the link you gave me for QEvents. Lets say I want to register an event via QEvent::registerEventType(). How does this function "register" an event? Does the class keep track of a private array of unregistered enums between 1000 and 65535? Is this new enum added to the list of enums under QEvent::Type, so I that I can do something like QEvent::CustomEvent?

Comment: These aren't, strictly speaking, enums any more, because these codes are managed at runtime (enums are generated at build-time). This functions registers new event-type code and guarantees that it won't be assigned again.

You cannot modify existing class ("do something like QEvent::CustomEvent"), and that points to whole C++, not Qt. So you can save your new registered code as shown in the link at Ad.2. (still, I'm talking about second answer, not the accepted one. You can also look at first comment to this answer).

Comment: cubuspl42 - my comment has nothing to do with the question or the answer but your comment - "IMO you didn't search hard." I am still wondering why did you have to write that ? The questioner has written about 5 short paragraphs and that suggests that the questioner has thought about the problem. It could have been the case that he/she didnt get from the forums what was wanted. If you didn't feel you should answer then you needn't. It was not mandatory for you to answer. You could have always kept quiet. But it is to be appreciated that you did answer.