# How to create custom wheel events in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I found multiple questions regarding custom `QEvents`. So since Qt 4 we have to derive from `QEvent` and register our custom type. There are some samples around.

What I want is a `QWheelEvent` with custom data in it. So the event should be usable everywhere as a "normal" `QWheelEvent` but if I want to I can check for my `CustomWheelEvent` type and retrieve the data from it.

The problem is that I don't know how to register the type because the constructor of the `QWheelEvent` does not offer the possibility to set the event type.

Looking at the internals of `QEvent` I could simply set the protected member Type t to an event type returned by `registerEventType()`. Does this have side-effects?

If I simply derive from `QWheelEvent` I can also use `dynamic_cast` to find out if it is my own event carrying my custom data. A simple static cast after a check for the type should be better though.

Any thoughts on this?

---

**Edit:** I have tried the approach with `dynamic_casts` but the cast seems to fail. This is possible if Qt deep-copies the event internally, so that a new `QWheelEvent` is created and passed through the event system instead of my `CustomWheelEvent`. This way my own data (defined in `CustomWheelEvent`) is stripped off the object and only the base class (`QWheelEvent`) is handled. I originally thought that the pointer is used as it is, so that I can rely on the `dynamic_cast`. More information on this is appreciated!

Comment: I wonder why an answer below (including my comment) got deleted. Is there a history of the thread? I'd like to ask the author about his or her reasons :-)

Comment: The author of an answer can always delete his posts. You need 10k rep to see deleted answers.

Comment: Thanks... so won't see it for a looooong time^^

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
[Qt: Defining a custom event type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248009/qt-defining-a-custom-event-type)

I think that you do want to register the event and that it will return a new unused type (number). In an example there, the static object sets the value to QEvent::None. The primary problem I see with the solution there is that it is not thread safe, so, be sure to make this thread safe somehow (like maybe call the static type method before things start so that they are initialized before it could be used in a multi-threaded way).

Comment: Hey Andrew, I've read the thread but as I mentioned in my question the QWheelEvent does not offer access to the constructor of QEvent. So I cannot configure the internals as I want. Maybe I don't understand you completely, so it would be great if you could give an example :-)